# How to show that the function belongs to $L_2(R)$ but does not belong to $L_1(R)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

How to show that $K$ does not belong to $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ but it belongs to $L_2(\mathbb{R})$?  $K$ is
$$
K(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lc}\frac{\sin(x)}{\pi x} & x\ne0 \\ \frac{1}{\pi} & x=0 \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Do you see that $K \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is easy? It would be helpful if you gave details on what you know and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave $K \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to you. Use the definition of what it means to be in $L^2$ and the bound $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$.

Observe that $K$ is continuous at $0$. Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
\pi\|K\|_{L^1} &\geq \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|} dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|} dx \\
&\geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)} \frac{|\sin (x)|}{2\pi(n+1)} dx\\
&= \frac{c}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}, 
\end{align*}
where $c = \int_{[0, 2\pi]} |\sin(x)| dx > 0.$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: $L_1$ part I understood. It is a nice trick to split the integration range. To my shame I do not see why it is integrable in $L_2$. Integral $\int 1/x^2 dx$ does not converge.

Comment: Ah, it is easy. sorry!